# How to use ITextSharp Image path such that it works after Setup

Tags: c#, pdf, installation, itext

In my code to create a PDF an Image is being put on the PDF page as logo. But after Setup this image path is obviously not working. Looking for a way around this problem. Below is the current code.

```
System.Drawing.Image pimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\dev\\C# .net\\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\\bin\\Debug\\spacecraft.jpg");
iTextSharp.text.Image ItextImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(pimage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ItextImage.ScalePercent(10f);
//ItextImage.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.Right, doc.Top );
ItextImage.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
doc.Add(ItextImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

A file path is not needed if the image is kept in debug. Just the name of the file followed by .filetype is sufficient. Hence it works even after SetUp file is created.